# python c extension: multithreading and random numbers

Tags: python, c, multithreading, random

I have implemented a work queue pattern in C (within a python extension) and I am disappointed with performance.

I have a simulation with a list of particles ("elements"), and I benchmark the time taken to perform all the calculations required for a timestep and record this along with the number of particles involved. I am running the code on a quad-core hyperthreaded i7, so I was expecting for performance to rise (time taken to fall) with the number of threads up to about 8, but instead the fastest implementation has no worker threads (functions are simply executed instead of added to the queue,) and with each worker thread the code gets slower and slower (by a step of more than the time for the unthreaded implementation for each new thread!) I've had a quick peek in my processor usage application, and it seems python never really exceeds 130% CPU usage, regardless of how many threads are running. The machine has plenty of headroom above that, overall system usage at about 200%.

Now part of my queue implementation (shown below) is choosing an item **at random** from the queue, since each work item's execution requires a lock on two elements and similar elements will be near each other in the queue. Thus, I want the threads to pick random indices and attack different bits of the queue to minimise mutex clashes.

Now, I've read that my initial attempt with `rand()` will have been slow because my random numbers weren't thread safe (does that sentence make sense? not sure...)

I've tried the implementation both with `random()` and with `drand48_r` (although, unfortunately, the latter seems to be unavailable on OS X,) to no avail with the statistics.

Perhaps someone else can tell me what might be the cause of the problem? the code (worker function) is below, and do shout if you think any of the queue_add functions or constructors might be useful to see too.

```c
void* worker_thread_function(void* untyped_queue) {

  queue_t* queue = (queue_t*)untyped_queue;
  int success = 0;
  int rand_id;
  long int temp;
  work_item_t* work_to_do = NULL;
  int work_items_completed = 0;

  while (1) {
    if (pthread_mutex_lock(queue->mutex)) {

      // error case, try again:
      continue;
    }

    while (!success) {

      if (queue->queue->count == 0) {

        pthread_mutex_unlock(queue->mutex);
        break;
      }

      // choose a random item from the work queue, in order to avoid clashing element mutexes.
      rand_id = random() % queue->queue->count;

      if (!pthread_mutex_trylock(((work_item_t*)queue->queue->items[rand_id])->mutex)) {

        // obtain mutex locks on both elements for the work item.
        work_to_do = (work_item_t*)queue->queue->items[rand_id];

        if (!pthread_mutex_trylock(((element_t*)work_to_do->element_1)->mutex)){ 
          if (!pthread_mutex_trylock(((element_t*)work_to_do->element_2)->mutex)) {

            success = 1;
          } else {

            // only locked element_1 and work item:
            pthread_mutex_unlock(((element_t*)work_to_do->element_1)->mutex);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(work_to_do->mutex);
            work_to_do = NULL;
          }
        } else {

          // couldn't lock element_1, didn't even try 2:
          pthread_mutex_unlock(work_to_do->mutex);
          work_to_do = NULL;
        }
      }
    }

    if (work_to_do == NULL) {
       if (queue->queue->count == 0 && queue->exit_flag) {

        break;
      } else {

        continue;
      }
    }

    queue_remove_work_item(queue, rand_id, NULL, 1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(work_to_do->mutex);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(queue->mutex);

    // At this point, we have mutex locks for the two elements in question, and a
    // work item no longer visible to any other threads. we have also unlocked the main
    // shared queue, and are free to perform the work on the elements.
    execute_function(
      work_to_do->interaction_function,
      (element_t*)work_to_do->element_1,
      (element_t*)work_to_do->element_2,
      (simulation_parameters_t*)work_to_do->params
    );

    // now finished, we should unlock both the elements:
    pthread_mutex_unlock(((element_t*)work_to_do->element_1)->mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(((element_t*)work_to_do->element_2)->mutex);

    // and release the work_item RAM:
    work_item_destroy((void*)work_to_do);
    work_to_do = NULL;

    work_items_completed++;
    success = 0;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like random() is your problem, since it is the same code regardless of number of threads.  Since performance goes down with number of threads, likely you are getting killed by locking overhead.  Do you really need multiple threads? How long does the work function take, and what is your average queue depth?  Selecting items randomly seems like a bad idea.  Definitely if queue count is <= 2 you don't need to do the rand calculation.  Also, instead of randomly selecting queue index, it would be better to just use a different queue per worker thread and insert in a round-robin fashion.  Or, at least something simple like remembering the last index claimed by previous thread and just not picking that one.

Comment: number of particles is anything from N = 100 to 100,000, and you need to do at least that number of calculations, probably more like 10N. For large numbers, timesteps can take up to a second, and when you need to run 50,000 of them to reach equillibrium... :) Thanks, though, a round robin might just do the trick to minimise locking without big fat random calculations.

Comment: You can do some profiling, but in general pseudorandom number generators like rand() (which would be good enough for this) are actually not very computationally intensive.  They can be implemented with a couple of multiplications and adds that overflow the result, or using a feedback shift register.  Cryptographic random generators can be heavyweight, but you definitely don't need that.

Comment: indeed, but round robin also reduces the need for other locking behaviour, and leaves all but one thread unhindered with a queue of work at any one time. half way through implementing it, but getting frustrating segfaults when more than one thread :/ so will know soon enough! :)

Comment: Thanks. The round robin strategy was the best, it seems. I'm yet to get any threaded code to actually run faster than the single threaded (presumably because the caching works really really well when single threaded) but I am at least using up over 600% CPU some of the time - meaning it is my code being slow not the mutexes! Thanks very much...

Answer (score 0):

Python threads aren't real threads. All python threads are run in the same OS level thread, and are executed one-at-a-time thanks to GIL - the Global Interpreter Lock. Rewriting your code with processes might do the trick, if the workers are relatively long-lived in the context.

[Wikipedia's page on GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock)

----Edit----

Right, this was in c. But GIL still matters. [Info on threads in c extensions](http://docs.python.org/faq/library.html#threads)

Comment: wait, Python is messing with the way I use system C libraries like pthread?! I thought C extensions were just as fast as pure C programs, during the bits written in C, no?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it manages to thwart your pthreads right out, but the behavior sounds exactly like what I'd expect from using regular python-threads. I'm not seeing anything specific about it in the documentation, as long as you aren't touching python objects in your thread. http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads

Comment: interesting. In this case, I'm not doing this, but there is a section of my code that might have. Thanks!

Comment: (apologies, I will pick this question back up when I've eliminated the hideous race condition I appear to have created.)

Answer (score 0):

To know if this is the bottleneck of your program, you'd have to benchmark and check, but it might well be possible.

`random()` and friends that have a hidden state variable can be severe bottlenecks for parallel programming. *If* they are made thread safe, this is usually done by just mutexing the access, so everything slows down.

The portable choice for a thread safe random generator on POSIX systems is `erand48`. In contrast to `drand48` it receives the state variable as an argument. You'd just have to keep a state variable on the stack of each thread (it is an `unsigned short[3]`) and call `erand48` with that.

Also keep in mind that these are *pseudo* random generators. If you use the same state variable between different threads your random numbers are not independent.